# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. (SSIS)

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS package (Azure Blob Upload task) to move files from On-Prem system to Azure blob. When I run the package this task takes aprox 40 mins and then fails with this error. It doesn't move file . Any help would be Appropriated

Comment: Try testing the package on a Windows Server 2019 environment.   The default TLS features and setting there seems to interoperate better as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error last week, turned out that no TLS was being used to make a connection with an external web api.
Used this in my proxy to set it to TLS1.2 explicitely :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I don't see any option to add this in Azure Blob Upload task in SSIS . where did you add this ?